# Windows Phone 8 - Adding a menu item to a media library item

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

When opening the media library for images, there is a menu with items like:

- send
- edit
- delete
- upload to SkyDrive

Is it possible to add an item to this menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx

this is what i wanted :)